# ToggleButton EventTriggerBehavior- binding image to background of togglebutton

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, behavior, eventtrigger

i have the following code in my xaml :

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="play"    Command="{Binding OnPlayButton}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=media , Mode=TwoWay}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="573,638,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" Width="50">
    <Image Name="MyImage"  Source="Images/Control/Play.png"/>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Checked">
            <core:ChangePropertyAction  PropertyName="MyImage" Value="{Binding Source=Images/Control/Pause.png}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Unchecked">
            <core:ChangePropertyAction   PropertyName="MyImage" Value="{Binding Source=Images/Control/Play.png}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ToggleButton>
```

What i'm trying to achieve is change the background of the togglebutton to pause.png when its clicked and change it to play.png when clicked again. I'm getting exception in the xaml , is this the correct way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there with Behaviors. But PropertyName is Not `Image` It is `Source`. And `TargetObject` is `MyImage`

Your code should be something like below.

```
<ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="True">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Checked">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=MyImage}" PropertyName="Source" Value="Images/Control/Pause.png" />
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Unchecked">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=MyImage}" PropertyName="Source" Value="Images/Control/Play.png"/>
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="Images/Control/Play.png" Width="100" Height="100"/>
</ToggleButton>
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Kindly thank you sir , this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `PropertyName="MyImage"` as "MyImage" is the name of a control, not a property of `ToggleButton`!

The easiest way to do what you want is to add the two images one after the other and change visibility according to the control state:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="play">
    <Image Source="Images/Control/Play.png" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=play, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" />
    <Image Source="Images/Control/Stop.png" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=play, Converter={StaticResource InverterBooleanToVisibilityConverter}" />
</ToggleButton>
```

On the example above I'm using two converter instances for something that converts a `bool` value to a `Visibility` value. You can write your own or just use a 3rd party one like the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` from [Cimbalino Toolkit](http://cimbalino.org).